# If I switch my laptop from UEFI BIOS to Legacy BIOS, does it affect my computer in any way?

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, efi

I want to switch my computer(Laptop) from UEFI/EFI BIOS to Legacy BIOS, but I don't know how to and I don't know if it will affect my computer in any way.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? As Jamie Hanrahan says, such a change will either render the computer unbootable or (depending on the design of the firmware) have no noticeable affect, so there's no possible advantage to be gained, absent some other factor. If you can say what you hope to achieve, perhaps a better alternative can be suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. You will not be able to boot. Your system and boot partitions are set up for UEFI and the Legacy BIOS will not be ablt to boot from them.

It is possible to fix this after such a change, but many have failed with the result that they lost all their data and installed programs - they had to reinstall Windows from scratch.

(terminology nitpick: There is no "UEFI BIOS". There is UEFI firmware, and there is legacy "PC BIOS" firmware.)